can not cite properly for one literature
I use latex to cite one of my literature. Before I add this literature, everything is fine, but after adding it, I cannot cite properly.
I am not using bibtex, just adding the new item in as
\begin{thebibliography}  
\bibitem{jiang2015effective}
H. Jiang, and M.~G. Chorzepa. An effective numerical simulation methodology to predict the impact response of pre-stressed concrete members. {\em Engineering Failure Analysis} 2015; 55:63--78.
\end{thebibliography}.

I cite this article in the main text, using \cite{jiang2015effective}, but it cannot be properly cited.  How to do with this?

I'm guessing you're seeing the error
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

thebibliography environment takes an argument to specify the widest label (Argument in "thebibliography"), this is missing from your snippet and would generate the above error.
Provide an argument and it will compile.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{jiang2015effective}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{jiang2015effective}
H. Jiang, and M.~G. Chorzepa. An effective numerical simulation methodology to predict the impact response of pre-stressed concrete members. {\em Engineering Failure Analysis} 2015; 55:63--78.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}


I also try to use bibtex to generate the literature, but I often met this problem. –
Here is my try.bib file @article{chen2023simplified,   title     = {A simplified method for quantifying the progressive collapse fragility of multi-story RC frames in China},   author    = {Chen, Zefan and Zhu, Yaqiong and Lu, Xinzheng and Lin, Kaiqi},   journal   = {Engineering Failure Analysis},   volume    = {143},   pages     = {106924},   year      = {2023},   publisher = {Elsevier} }   But when I use bibtex , it give me such error "I cannot open database file try.bib",

That is a totally different question. If I cannot open database file try.bib is the first error bibtex gives, either try.bib is not accessible (put it in the same folder as the tex/aux file and make sure it's correctly named), or it's possible a character in the working directory (spaces being the usual offender) is tripping up bibtex.
